# How to use ContentProvider to implement Intent. ACTION_SEND?

Tags: android, android-contentprovider, android-fileprovider

I was using using Intent.ACTION_SEND to send files to other devices. I did it very well with Lolipop(with file Uri). But When I tried with Naugat, It was giving Exception, then i get to know that I have to use Content Uri rather than File Uri. I could use FileProvider, but what i am trying to share is inside "/system/app","/data/app",and "/mnt/asec"(you probably know what i am trying to do :)) and FileProvider does not allow(or i don't know yet) access to those folders. Someone in stackoverflow told me that i should use ContentProvider, but it was too overwhelming for me. All I am asking is, is there any way to do this with FileProvider? If not, can anyone show me how to implement such content provider? I Searched everywhere I can,but did not find anything that can help. I know that the question is not clear,but blv me, i am not clear at all :( .

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<paths>
<'what should i use here?'external-path name="device_app_path" 
path="/system"/>
<external-path name="sd_card_app_path" path="/data"/>
<external-path name="system_app_path" path="/mnt/asec"/>
</paths>
```

I know that 'external-path' does not contain '/system' , or '/data'. Please tell what i should place there if it is possible

Comment: You only need to implement query(), getType() and openFile(). Just start with logging all calls with all parameter values and you will soon see what is asked.

Comment: `Searched everywhere I can,but did not find anything that can help. ` Hard to believe. I googled for contentprovider example for files and immediately found: http://blog.evizija.si/android-contentprovider/ . There is all you need.